# Freshdesk Webhook - Get data from subject to populate a custom field

Tags: webhooks, freshdesk

Has anyone tried to get a string from a ticket subject and populate a custom field using Webhooks on Freshdesk?

I am trying to get a reservation number that starts with the letter 'R' and put it on a custom field.

Example code:

```
     <script>
var strng;  
    strng = "Either way, time largely defines the human experience.";  
    var incStr = strng.includes("human");  
    document.write("Is 'human' present in the string? : " + incStr);
</script>

{
"custom_fields": {"Resv#": incStr}

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp09G.png)

Comment: Please post some code, you've tried and how the ticket subject, custom field looks like.

Comment: <script>
var strng;  
    strng = "Either way, time largely defines the human experience.";  
    var incStr = strng.includes("human");  
    document.write("Is 'human' present in the string? : " + incStr);
</script>

{
"custom_fields": {"Resv#": incStr}

}